# Syntax Error when inserting data with variables in MySQLdb Python

Tags: python, mysql, insert, mysql-python

I am trying to insert some data into a MySQL DB with Python and MySQLdb. When i do the following:

```
query = "INSERT INTO universitats (universitat) VALUES ('%s')" % (lloc)
cursor.execute(query)
db.commit()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read.py", line 39, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Hospitalet de Llobregat')' at line 1")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you also provide some of the lines of code preceding `query=...` which can help explain the value of `lloc` and the design of `universitats`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lines:

```
 query = "INSERT INTO universitats (universitat) VALUES ('%s')" % (lloc)
 cursor.execute(query)
```

should look like this

```
query = "INSERT INTO universitats (universitat) VALUES (%s)"  
cursor.execute(query,(lloc,))
```

and then commit.